# Add or remove item to <li> based on checkboxes selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've four checkboxes in one div.

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="101">  This is 101
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="102">  This is 102
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="103">  This is 103
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" value="104">  This is 104
</div>
```

Now on each click, I want to insert/remove a `<li>` item on another div that's on the right hand side when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. Another div:

```
<div id="items">
    <ul id="itemList">
    </ul>
```

Am doing something like this:

```
$("#chkbox").click(function() {
            // If checked
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                //add to the right
                $a = $(this).val();
                $("#itemList").append('<li>'+$a+'</li>');
            }
            else {
                //hide to the right
                $("#itemList").slideUp("fast", function () {
                        $("#itemList").child.remove();
                    });
            }
        });
```

This doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: IDs are supposed to **uniquely identify** items. You are using the same ID (chkbox) multiple times. You probably want to use a class instead.

Comment: do you mean in every corresponding checkbox there is an li that will be remove and not remove them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the following issues:

- Change multiple elements with the same `id` to a `class`
- Use `change` event instead of `click`
- identify which checkbox referes your items. For this I'm using `data` attr.

```
$(".chkbox").change(function() {
    // If checked
    var value = $(this).val(),
        $list = $("#itemList");
    if (this.checked) {
        //add to the right
        $list.append("<li data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</li>");
    }
    else {
        //hide to the right
        $list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CL2tA/)

Comment: Thanks! Now, suppose there are duplicates in the checkbox. Say 101 is present multiple times. How will I check before adding to the right if it's already in <li>? Based on Ricardo Lohmann's answer, the below JS doesn't work. if (this.checked) { //add to the right but check if it exists if($list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]')) { alert(value); } else { alert("not found");} This alerts the value on every checkbox selection, irrespective if it exists or not in the <li>

Comment: Got it. I should've used $list.find(...).length

Answer (score 2):

IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead, And also note that jQuery object doesn't have `child` property, you should use `children` method instead, however it seems you only want to remove one element, you can use `contains` selector.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="101">  This is 101
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $list = $("#itemList");

    $(".chkbox").change(function() {
        var a = this.value;
        if (this.checked) {
            $list.append('<li>' + a + '</li>');
        }
        else {
            $("#itemList li:contains('"+a+"')").slideUp(function(){
               $(this).remove();
            })
        }

    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhqh5/

Answer (score 2):

undefined is right you need to change your `id chkbox` to `class chkbox`. I have modified your javascript to give the effect you are going for. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wwgc/).

```
$(".chkbox").click(function() { 
    var a = $(this).val();  //store the value of clicked .chkbox
    // If checked           
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {  
        //add to the right                
        $("#itemList").append('<li>'+a+'</li>'); //append li to list           
    }            
    else {                
    //hide to the right                
        $("#itemList > li").each(function(){// go through all of the li elements
            if($(this).text() == a){ //check if text is equal to a
                $(this).slideUp('fast', function(){ //slide up the li and then remove it
                    $(this).remove();
                 });
            }                   
        });             
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on my understanding on your question, you mean to remove or add a corresponding `<li>` base on a certain checkbox.

You must use a class so you can use a single style rule for you checkboxes if in case

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="101">  This is 101
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="102">  This is 102
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="103">  This is 103
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="104">  This is 104
</div>
<div>
    <ul id="itemList"></ul>
</div>
```

and this will be the JS that will work base on what I understand on your question

```
 $(".chkbox").click(function() {
            // If checked
            $a = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                //add to the right
                $("#itemList").append('<li id="'+$a+'">'+$a+'</li>');
            }
            else {
                //hide to the right

                        $("#" + $a).remove();

            }
        });
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/5PMkA/